# IBM Z Xplore JCL1 challenge Abend U4038

Tags: jcl

In the JCL1 challenge, I tried changing the member name for output from `NAME` to `COMBINED` but the User Abend U4038 continues to be raised.

```
Original 
//FULLNAME DD DSN=&SYSUID..OUTPUT(NAMES),DISP=SHR

Modified
//FULLNAME DD DSN=&SYSUID..OUTPUT(COMBINED),DISP=SHR
```

Then this weird thing happened, I reran my JCL1 job and it showed an error even though I didn't change anything.

```
ERROR at JOBS
  "JCL1(JOB03785) - JCL ERROR " 

Rather than
  "JCL1(JOB03785) - CC 0000"
```

Comment: Please post the fill JCL, and the full output from the job and **format as code* so that it is easy to read and copy&paste. We're reading the crytsal ball to figure out the details.

Comment: Can you provide, in addition to the comments from @phunsoft a link to the "JCL1 Challenge"  I presume this is part of some educational program.  Showing the actual abend information from the Job Output is helpful as I suspect there are other items in the output that would help to understand what is going on.  

Note that a U abend is a user abend and is generally from a user component and not a system failure.  

Can you provide the dataset attributes of &SYSUID..OUTPUT which will also help.

Comment: So, you have removed the superfluous parenthesis at the end of the statements. Was that a cut&paste error, or did you have then in the JCL? Again, please post the job's output, files 1-3. File 3 has the error messages, and they point to file 2.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on line 13 of the JCL and you need to change //COMBINE to //COMBINED
I don't know if you still need help with this but in case you or anyone else does, I'll leave this here as I came across it when I was stuck at the same step. Thank you for creating a thread for this specific stumper!
[Level 1, Challenge 3, Step 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjNho.png)